# jupyter notebook error after upgrading anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

yesterday i updated my anaconda to version (1.9.12)

im getting the following error & 500 internal error when using notebook

An invalid notebook may not function properly. The validation error was:
Notebook validation failed: 2 is less than the minimum of 3:
2

the code is running but i cant save,edit or download notebooks

i looked online and someone suggested to run: conda update --all 
i did but still not working i have restarted my pc several times now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this error is sometimes caused by old nbformat versions? 
See https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1352

Try listing the version you have installed, and if it's 2, then maybe try updating (`conda update nbformat`)